A Question From Number Theory
Suppose that $n \gt 1$ is an odd positive integer. define $A$ and $B$ as follows:
$$
A_n := \{ a: 1\leq a\leq n, \, (a,n)=1, \, \left(\frac{a}{n}\right) = 1\} , \, 
B_n := \{ b: 1\leq b\leq n, \, (b,n)=1, \, \left(\frac{b}{n}\right) = -1\}.
$$
$\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)$ denotes the Jacobi Symbol.
We know that for prime $n$, $|A_n| = |B_n|$.
But the problem here is to determine those numbers $n$, such that the above equality also holds for them.
I guess that for numbers with at least a prime factor with an odd power the equality holds. Actually, it is enough to prove my statement for square-free numbers, but I do not know how to prove it.
Thank you for your time.

Title is too generic. How about something like 'Comparison of cardinality of sets of invertible modular residues with the same jacobi symbol value.'

Notice that if $B_n$ is nonempty, then $|A_n|=|B_n|$. Indeed, if $b_0 \in B_n$, then $b \mapsto b_0b$ mod $n$ induces a bijection from $B_n$ to $A_n$ (check this).
Hence it suffices to check when $B_n$ is nonempty. If $n = p_1^{\alpha_1}\dots p_s^{\alpha_s}$, the Jacobi symbol splits as $(\frac{x}{n}) = (\frac{x}{p_1})^{\alpha_1} \times \dots \times (\frac{x}{p_s})^{\alpha_s}$. If all $\alpha_i$'s are even, then this product is always 1, and $B_n$ is empty. But as soon as one $\alpha_i$ is odd, it follows from the case of primes and the chineese remainder theorem that $B_n$ is nonempty, and we are done.
Hence the result holds if and only if $n \ge 3$ is not a square. You can see this for yourself on the wikipedia page.
